# Circular reference between resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, resources

I have a template selector resource that is declared as:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="BooleanPortTemplate.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="StringPortTemplate.xaml" />

  <common:TestStepPortTemplateSelector x:Key="portTemplateSelector"
                                       BooleanPortTemplate="{StaticResource booleanPortTemplate}"                                   
                                       StringPortTemplate="{StaticResource stringPortTemplate}"/>
```

and used as:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1"
                    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource portTemplateSelector}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Value,
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I want to add a new port type that contains other ports, so my template should know about the template selector and the template selector should know about my template. This brings up two errors:

1. The resource I place above won't see the other resource.
2. I get the "A loop was detected in the property expression" xaml error.

How can I solve these problems and make the recursive UI generate?

Errors in code:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BooleanPortTemplate.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="StringPortTemplate.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary>

      <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />



      <common:TestStepPortTemplateSelector x:Key="portTemplateSelectorKey2"
                                           BlockPortTemplate="{StaticResource blockPortTemplate}"
                                           BooleanPortTemplate="{StaticResource booleanPortTemplate}"                                       
                                           StringPortTemplate="{StaticResource stringPortTemplate}"/>



      <DataTemplate x:Key="blockPortTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Style="{StaticResource MainPortGridStyle}">

          <ListView Grid.Column="0"
                    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource portTemplateSelectorKey2}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Value,
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        </Grid>

      </DataTemplate>


    </ResourceDictionary>
```

> The blockPortTemplate cannot be located because it's under the
>   selector and the ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource
>   portTemplateSelectorKey2}" row signals a "loop was detected in the
>   property exception." xaml error.

Comment: Can you paste the actual errors, this is confusing

Comment: Edited post to show what exactly is the problem.